# Does the iOS MAM-based Authentication model make sense?

Tags: ios, authentication, enterprise

I've been reviewing Apple's MAM-based SSO framework. It looks like this approach is really about authenticating to back-end services, rather than authenticating to the app itself. And, while I understand that service endpoints usually require some form of authentication, it seems odd to make that the basis of an AuthN framework of the *app*. I can think of many dysfunctional results...

1. If there is local data on the device there is would be no authentication challenge for getting to it, since accessing it might not trip a network call
2. There would be a weird user experience as the app challenges the user at what seem to be random points (when the authenticated session times out)
3. If there are multiple back-end services (e.g. 1 enterprise endpoint and 1 cloud-based service) the solution would only cover one service and you would have to somehow incorporate both into a decent user experience

What am I missing?  Hopefully I'm misreading this because I love staying in the Apple iOS ecosystem for solutions. This one just seems like its not going to do the job.

Comment: Which framework are you referring to?  Can you provide a link?  Apple,s philosophy is that iOS devices are personal devices and as such there isn't an overall need for access control and authentication within an app for local data (obviously some apps do implement protection for sensitive data to protect against "snooping"). You would a,so typically use the keychain to hold credentials so that the initial response to an authentication challenge can be automated, with the user only prompted if that fails due to changed credentials

Comment: Hi Paulw - in the enterprise space MAM there is a whole set of frameworks and vendors to facilitate securing corporate data. Here is a article about the AuthN / SSO framework- https://samuelyates.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/kerberos-single-sign-on-in-ios-7/

Comment: Ahh ok. So you are referring to per-app VPN. That is why i was confused; I was not aware of any SSO framework in the sense that, say, Core Location is a framework. The VPN is happening in the iOS network layer and so the app has no idea that it is there. The app accesses the network normally and iOS activates the VPN as required. This can result in authentication prompts at unexpected times and that is one of the reasons why VPNs and mobile devices tend to be a user-unfriendly mix.

Answer (score 0):

After looking deeper and talking with AirWatch engineers, here's what I've concluded:

1. For user authentication (user launching and authenticating to the app), the Apple MAM integrated auth framework is not really what you want. That framework is really about working against back-end enterprise services (only).
2. For service authentication, yes, the MAM integrated authentication framework makes a lot of sense. It is built around the challenge model and credentials can be supplied at runtime - username/password, client certificate,..etc. The basic behavior is that a service endpoint challenges with an HTTP 401 and the NSURLSession delegate is given an opportunity to respond. The recommended approach is to use the iOS "protection space" capability which associates a protected URL domain/realm with the credentials that will satisfy the challenge. (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtectionSpace_Class/)

Seems like the best approach for meeting both is to use a separate user authentication solution up front to do the user auth, then use the MAM integrated auth framework for service invocations. The "join point" here is that the credentials from user auth can be applied to the iOS protection space.

We are currently POCing the AirWatch SDK for integrating this authentication flow into a SSO experience. The credentials should be able to be applied to the protection space, removing our app code from any significant credentials handling.

Btw, there is an excellent write up on protection spaces with URL sessions in a book called "iOS Application Security" by David Thiel.  If you are doing iOS app security its a must have.